# Why inner join is slower than separate queries

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have following tables

### users table

- columns : id, email
- index on : id

### locations table

- columns -> id, name, user_id, last_scan_time
- index on : id, user_id

### items table

- columns -> id, name, location_id, last_scan_time
- index on : id, location_id

I have to run this query to get items

```
select items.* from items 
inner join locations on (items.last_scan_time = locations.last_scan_time and      items.location_id = locations.id)
inner join users on (locations.user_id = users.id and users.email = 'abc@abc.com')
```

Above query takes 13 secs for 1056870 rows

Now if I split each query separately instead of joins it takes much lesser time

```
select id from users where email = 'abc@abc.com'
0.0 sec

select id,last_scan_time from locations where user_id = #user-id-returned-from-above-query#
0.0 sec

select * from items where last_scan_time = #last_scan_time-from-above-query# and  location_id = #location-id-from-above-query#
0.01 sec
```

What changes to the join query or indexes I have to make to make the join query run faster than total time of individual queries?

Please help.

Thank you,
Sachin

Comment: `explain [your query]` will tell you what's happening. in particular, which indexes are (not?) being used.

Comment: If you want us to help optimize a query, **you need to show us the actual table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly.  If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is of the form (reformatted):

```
SELECT i.* 
  FROM items i
  JOIN locations l 
    ON l.last_scan_time = i.last_scan_time
   AND l.id = i.location_id
  JOIN users u
    ON u.id = l.user_id 
   AND u.email = 'abc@abc.com'
```

So basically, the predicates in the query are:

- eq literal on `email` column of `users` table
- eq ref on `user_id` column of `locations` table
- eq ref on `location_id` and `last_scan_time` of `items` table

That suggests that for this particular query, the optimum indexes might be something like:

```
... ON users (email,id)

... ON locations (id, last_scan_time)

... ON items (location_id, last_scan_time)
```

But this suggestion really depends on the actual table definitions, whether the tables are MyISAM or InnoDB, the cardinality and data distribution, and so on.

I recommend you use `EXPLAIN <query>` to get the query execution plan.

Comment: Thanks Spencer7953, adding index on email worked well, it cut down time to 0.05 sec from 13 sec for the original query.  Also many thanks to commenters for pointing to EXPLAIN and cardinality values. It helped a lot in optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

A better example is that if you wanted to run a query that involved the intersection of two sets of data that were somewhat separate sections of data... like for example if you have a table of Events, Events have EventTypes and EventTypes have an attribute "Singles Only". You then have a Users table, Users have MaritalStatus, and MaritalStatus has a flag "Single". You of course also have an Attending table mapping Events to Users.

If you wanted to know if any Non-Singles were signed up to go to your Singles Only events, the right answer is not to write a single query joining these tables together by ID and then just sort it out in a where clause. Its better to get one result that is Users with UserTypes that aren't single, JOIN that result to Attending JOINED to a Select that is only selecting Events with EventTypes that are Singles Only. Formatting in that way means that the JOINs around the Attendance table aren't joining and returning users that ARE single, and aren't matching Events that AREN'T Singles Only.